# Does any one know the 'top' command 's result's meaning in android?

Tags: android, linux, command

I have found the result of 'top' is different from result of in standard linux.I have searched on the web a little bit but I can not find my answer.
For example, following is the partial result of top in my android:

```
  PID CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
  814   2% R     1    940K    372K  fg root     top
  110   1% S    58 185000K  59216K  fg system   system_server
   31   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     vsync_workqueue
   49   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     file-storage
   52   0% S     1      0K      0K  fg root     gp2a_wq
  178   0% S     9  98476K  23820K  fg system   com.android.systemui
```

So #THR probably is the number of threads.But what is 'PCY'? I can not find this information in the /proc/(PID)/  folder. And I have found that if I open an youtube, the PCY will be fg. Then if I quit it(youtube), the youtube process still exists but the PCY will be bg. 
And in terms of 'S', I have found all processes are always 'S' which means sleeping, even my youtube app is currently active. It's weired...

Does anyone have any clue:> Thx

Comment: fg and bg certainly mean foreground vs. background.

Comment: OH, I think the fg and bg probably mean 'foreground' and 'background' :>

Comment: @Ken White  OK.I see. But I need to know such information because I need to use it in my programming.I think I can not get such information just use the API provided by android:<

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's my (un)educated guesses:

PID - Process ID

CPU% - CPU Usage

S - State (or possibly status) R=Running, S=Sleeping

#THR - Number of threads

PCY - I'm kinda stumped here.  You seem to have a pretty good grasp of what it does, so that's good enough (assuming that fg and bg are the only possible values)

UID - Name of the user that started the task

Name - This one is self-explanatory...

VSS and RSS:  From http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/e6f2d396a68238ad?pli=1

Virtual Set Size (sometimes abbreviated VSZ) and Resident Set Size. 
 Googling will turn up some detailed info for Linux.  Here's the high 
 speed version:

VSS indicates how much virtual memory is associated with the process, 
 Resident Set Size indicates how many physical pages are associated 
 with the process.

VSS is generally meaningless on Android.  If I memory-map a 1MB file, 
 VSS grows by 1MB, but I haven't used any resources (other than entries 
 in a virtual mapping table).

RSS is partially meaningless on Android, because it doesn't identify 
 pages shared between multiple processes.  If process A has an RSS of 
 2MB, and process B has an RSS of 2MB, it's possible that there are 4MB 
 of physical pages occupied.  It's also possible that there are only 
 2MB of physical pages occupied.

EDIT:
As far as your Youtube is sleeping deal, if it isn't actively doing anything, it will be sleeping, even if it is in the foreground.  Try creating a simple app that is basically while(1){Do something meaningless} and see if it is sleeping or running.  Granted it also might be a quirk with the way that Android handles multitasking.

EDIT2:
Mostly-uneducated-somewhat-random-stab-in-the-dark for PCY --
PCY -- Policy -- Determines how an app should be treated by Android's memory manager
FG -- Foreground -- Process is considered a foreground process and should not be killed to free mmemory
BG -- Background -- Process is considered a background process (not actively running in foreground and may be killed to free memory)

Answer (score 3):

top sourcecode [ top sourcecode][1]

[1]: http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/system/core/toolbox/top.c#442   to get the complete logic of how each value is calculated

Answer (score -1):

Try [`man top`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?top) on any normal linux / unix (though I don't think Android has man installed by default).

Actually now I look it looks like those column titles aren't mentioned on that `man` page, but the point stands that `man` is usually the best place to start looking for information about linux / unix commands.

Comment: But I do not think I can do it in Android using adb.It shows that command not found.

Comment: @HaoShen fair enough, but even if you're not running Linux/Unix already you might find it useful to have a Linux machine on hand (maybe a Ubuntu installed on a VirtualBox VM) to help you understand how Linux works on Android.

Comment: @therefromhereYes.THx.Anyway, I think I got my answer.Pcy means background or foreground:>

Answer (score -1):

this [page](http://elinux.org/Android_Memory_Usage) says what VSS and RSS mean, but does not specify how to obtain the  more meaningful PSS and USS