# adb shell top shows my application in foreground but actually its in background

Tags: android, adb, scheduler, cgroups

I have Android application with some services that bind to some process.

I found that `adb shell top -n 1` returns:

```
PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
31647  0   1% S    70 1733640K  98960K  bg u0_a132  com.my.app.dev
31727  0   1% S    29 1523892K  62924K  fg u0_a132  com.my.app.dev:myService
```

**Even when my application stays in background, why `top` `PCY` tells `'fg'` a.e. foreground?**

Can somebody spread the light on this issue?

This is my Manifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="com.my.app.dev" 
          android:versionName="4.0.1.6700000"
          android:versionCode="5033" >
    
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
              android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    
    
    
    
        
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:label="@string/config_app_name" 
                 android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionBarAppCompat" 
                 android:name="com.my.app.Mine" > 
                 
        <!-- we would prefer the launchMode to be standard, but it causes a lot of problems. -->
        <activity android:name="com.my.ui.main.MineApp" 
                  android:label="@string/config_app_name"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask" 
                  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" 
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent.NoActionBarAppCompat" >

            <intent-filter>      
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="mine.action.HomeActivity" />
                
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        
        
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                   android:value="xxxxxx" />
        
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        
        
        
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
        
        
    
        
        <service android:name="com.my.engine.logic.EngineService" 
                 android:process=":myService">
            <intent-filter>
                
                <action android:name="com_my_RemoteService" />
                <action android:name="com_my_EngineService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        
        

        
                
        <receiver 
          android:name="com.my.engine.analytics.ReferrerReceiver" 
          android:exported="true" android:process=":myService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
              android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
        <receiver 
              android:name="com.my.engine.BootBroadcastReceiver" 
              android:process=":myService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver 
             android:name="com.my.engine.util.MineWatcherReceiver" 
             android:process=":myServiceWatcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
       android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action   
       android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
                <action 
       android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action 
       android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    
        <receiver 
           android:name="com.my.engine.logic.InitServiceReceiver" 
           android:exported="true" android:process=":myService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="initServiceCheck"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver 
            android:name="com.my.engine.logic.UpdateCounterReceiver" 
            android:exported="true" android:process=":myService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="updateCustomCounter"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
        <receiver 
         android:name="com.my.engine.logic.PackageChangeReceiver" 
         android:process=":myService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action  
              android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                <action 
              android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action 
              android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                <action 
              android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
        <!-- for notification try next action -->
        <service android:name="com.my.notifications.actions.TryNextNotificationActionService" />
        
        <receiver android:name="com.my.ui.base.EulaReminderReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="eulaReminderAction" />         
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
        <receiver android:name="com.my.ui.base.MineGuiBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="finishStoppedActivities" /> 
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        
        <service android:name="com.my.infra.motion.ActivityRecognitionService"
                 android:label="ActivityRecognitionService"
                 android:exported="true"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:process=":myService">
        </service>
        
    </application>
    
</manifest>
```

---

**Edit 1**

I even stopped Notifications from Settings but still `process=":myService` in foreground

**Edit 2**

from [sources](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/system/core/toolbox/top.c#442):

```
if (p == SP_BACKGROUND)
        strcpy(proc->policy, "bg");
    else if (p == SP_FOREGROUND)
        strcpy(proc->policy, "fg");
    else
        strcpy(proc->policy, "er");
```

from  [Answer in other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051152/does-any-one-know-the-top-command-s-results-meaning-in-android):

> Mostly-uneducated-somewhat-random-stab-in-the-dark for PCY --
>
> PCY -- Policy -- Determines how an app should be treated by Android's
> memory manager
>
> FG -- Foreground -- Process is considered a foreground
> process and should not be killed to free memory
>
> BG -- Background --
> Process is considered a background process (not actively running in
> foreground and may be killed to free memory)

Comment: @PaulRatazzi, I was considering marking it as a duplicate myself for a moment. But the linked answer is not accurate in the specific part related to the `PCY` column, so I decided against it.

Comment: Agreed. I removed the flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Alex P.'s answer:

I believe the PCY column refers to the `cgroup` that the process is assigned to. Android defines two `cgroup` groups, `SP_FOREGROUND` and `SP_BACKGROUND`. The actual `cgroup` name for `SP_BACKGROUND` is `bg_non_interactive`. These groups are indicated in `top` with the abbreviations `fg` and `bg`, respectively.

You can find references to these throughout the Framework, most notably in `Process.java`, `IPCThreadState.cpp` and the native code in `android_util_Process.cpp` that interfaces with the Linux `/proc` filesystem to manage various aspects of the running processes.  According to source code commenting in these files, it seems that all threads in the foreground `cgroup` are scheduled with a 'normal' share of the CPU, while those in the background `cgroup` are scheduled with a 'reduced' share.

As for the definitions of normal and reduced, [this](https://github.com/keesj/gomo/wiki/AndroidScheduling) blog states that `SP_BACKGROUND` threads are limited to 5% CPU usage. You can confirm this by looking in `/dev/cpuctl/bg_non_interactive/cpu.shares` on your running device. On my Nexus 5 running AOSP 5.1, I get:

```
root@hammerhead:/ # cat /dev/cpuctl/bg_non_interactive/cpu.shares              
52
root@hammerhead:/ #
```

Here, 52 refers to the number of 'CPU shares' allowed for threads in the `cgroup`, out of a maximum of 1024 shares. So in this case `bg_non_interactive` threads are indeed allowed a maximum of ~5% CPU usage total for all the threads in the group.

In any case, it's clear that foreground and background in this context has little to do with Android's [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png) and the idea of foreground and background apps. It's simply the way that Android leverages Linux's `cgroups` facility.

Comment: Thank you Paul, it makes my understanding more clear

Answer (score 2):

`PCY` stands for `scheduling policy`. `fg` in that column means that the process gets higher priority than `bg`. It does not mean that the process is running in foreground.

Comment: Thanks, your answer and @Paul's makes sense